# Remove status messages from content output?

Tags: theming, 8

I want to move status messages into a region, but I can't seem to get it to stop being output as part of the main content output.

I tried this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['region'] == 'content' && isset($variables['elements']['messages'])) {
    unset($variables['elements']['messages']);
    //$variables['elements']['messages']['#printed'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

While that removed it from the array, it is still being rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at /admin/structure/block, you can find the block "Status Messages" and move it to the "- None-" region, or another region of your choosing.

Comment: edit nevermind, looks like the block placement didnt save or something. Moving the block now removes it from content.

Comment: @oknate, yes, messages are now in a block. The block gets the messages directly from `drupal_get_messages()` and no longer from the variable `messages`. The code from page.html.twig must be from an old version, it does not work like this anymore.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer to remove that portion.  Thanks.